# Display div after page reload

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to reload my page with javascript and then display a div.

The problem is that with the following code the div is displayed first and then the page reloads:

Part of my fetch function:

```
.then(result => {
  window.location.reload()
  document.querySelector('#cambiosguardados').style.display = 'block'
})
```

Is there any way to achieve this? The div is a success message I would like to display but I can't find a way to make this work.

Comment: Success message after reload? Can you elaborate your use case? Why a reload is needed to show success message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Easy Solution

You need a way to store the state as when the page reloads the state will reset.

You can try this

```
.then(result => {
  window.localStorage.setItem('show_div', 'true');
  window.location.reload();
})
```

and then some where else on your page

```
if(window.localStorage.getItem('show_div') == 'true') {
  document.querySelector('#cambiosguardados').style.display = 'block';
} else {
  document.querySelector('#cambiosguardados').style.display = 'none';
}
```

and then if you ever need to reset it you can use

```
window.localStorage.removeItem('show_div');
```

Answer (score 0):

When the page is refreshed the entire DOM is re-initialized for this reason this is not possible by refreshing the url, what you can do is send a flag and identify that value like this

**OPTION 1: Reload and show message**

```
.then(result => {
    var sucessUrl = new URL(location.href);
    sucessUrl.searchParams.set('success', 1);
    window.location.href = sucessUrl;
})
```

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
   const success = urlParams.get('success');
   if(success == 1'){
     document.querySelector('#cambiosguardados').style.display = 'block'
   } 
});
```

**OPTION 2: Show message and reload**

```
  document.querySelector('#cambiosguardados').style.display = 'block'
  setTimeout(function () { // wait 1 seconds and reload
     window.location.reload();
  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, when the page reloads the JavaScript is going to run again.

Why do you need to reload the page? Why can't you just display the div, what does the reload matter?

You could use search paramaters. So say you window.location.href = "/?success=true"

Then just in the script file at the top you can have a function that calls on load

```
(function popUp() {
    let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams
    let isSuccess = params.get("success")

    isSuccess && document.querySelector('#cambiosguardados').style.display = "block"
})()
```